# Multiple monitors simple workspace sharing

Tags: multiple-monitors, compiz, workspaces

I currently have the following config of workspaces:

```
1  2
3  4
```

If I plug a second monitor in is there a way to switch simply to:

```
1  |  2
3  |  4
```

I.e. no change to the configuration, but simply having two workspaces stacked vertically on each monitor. I'd be happy if they changed together and if horizontal movement was disabled.

Does any configuration like this exist, and secondly how quickly is it possible to move between configs?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, gnome without Unity.